# How do i show UIImageview with Animation?

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation, uiimageview

I have one **UIImageView** with round image I want to show ripple effect on the image. How can I show ripple effect on UIImageview with animation? Can anyone suggest?

Comment: show your tried code

Comment: I am not sure we can do it with only one image .... :d

Comment: self.imgView.animationImages = self.imageArray
        self.imgView.animationDuration = 1.0
        self.imgView.animationRepeatCount = 0
        self.imgView.startAnimating() . @Anbu.Karthik

Comment: i had tried with array also @mukesh_lokare

Comment: thank you. this is helpful to me  @ Dixit Akabari

Answer (score 0):

You can use **CATransition** to show any kind of effect. Here is sample code for it.

```
CATransition *animation = [CATransition animation];
[animation setDelegate:self];
[animation setDuration:2.0f];
[animation setTimingFunction:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut];
[animation setType:@"rippleEffect" ];
[YOUR_IMAGE_VIEW.layer addAnimation:animation forKey:NULL];
```

Checkout [this apple](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/quartzcore/catransition) document, so you will get more idea.

Here is a demo from [Jake Chasan](https://github.com/jakechasan/CATransition-Demo) about different types of animation.